# Sponsorship for travelling

Tags: international-travel

I want to travel world, I want someone who sponsor me to travel. I am planning to write blogs wherever I travel.

How Can I find sponsors for my trips?

Comment: Check out https://www.gofundme.com/.

Comment: this platform don't work here in Pakistan, sadly :(

Comment: This site cannot help people find travel sponsors. We can only answer specific fact-based questions about travel. See the [help center](/help/on-topic) for details.

Comment: I am not asking you to sponsor me, I want to know that how we I can find sponsorship

Comment: If you do not have established blogs with enough readers to demonstrate your travel blogs will be valuable you are unlikely to get sponsorship. If you do have established blogs, you have a set of people who read what you write and want to read more of it. Ask them for suggestions.

Comment: Can you please edit in what you have already done to build up your travel blogger reputation, (do not re-post the link to a blog which does not yet has many posts.) Have you traveled a lot in your own country? Have you written other content, (language does not matter,) which can be found online? Unless you improve your question it will get closed as not on topic, as we are not the site to help you travel.

Comment: @Pardeep Kumar You could start by asking family and friends to sponsor you. But you’ll need to find a niche travel topic or angle that hasn’t been covered up to now and build up your travel blogger reputation successfully to stand any chance of getting freebies/perks

Answer (score 3):

Sponsorship has several different meanings.

- In some cases, a **visa sponsor** is a company which makes a job offer and helps to get an employment visa.
- In other cases, a **visa sponsor** is a person who promises to pay for your stay and sometimes any costs of overstay.
- And then there is the **advertising sponsor**, who pays people to get publicity for their product or service.

There are cases where journalists and even blog writers get free hotel stays, in the expectation that they will write (positively) about their sponsors. But to get into that, one needs to be a recognized [influencer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influencer_marketing) to start with. First you need a successful blog, then **maybe** there will be some invitations and perks.

We can't help you getting that. And it is probably difficult in the Corona age, anyway.